# IBM Liberty 8.5.5.5 running in CICS v5.1 does not recognize CICS

Tags: websphere-liberty

After upgrading IBM liberty in CICS (v5.1) from 8.5.5.0 to 8.5.5.5, JCICS API is not recognized by liberty. same server.xml was copied and it has following features. I noticed different message in the log (messages listed below) with tag "LIBERTY NOTUSAGE". Anybody seen this ? Do we need change any config files ?

`<featureManager>
     <feature>cicsts:core-1.0</feature>
     <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
     <feature>wab-1.0</feature>
     <feature>blueprint-1.0</feature>
     <feature>cicsts:security-1.0</feature>
 </featureManager>`

Message from Liberty message log (8.5.5.0)

```
     product = WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0 (wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951)
```

Message from Liberty message log (8.5.5.5)

```
product = CICS Transaction Server for z/OS 5.1.0, CICS LIBERTY NOTUSAGE, WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5, WAS FOR Z/OS 8.5.5.5 (wlp-1.0.8.cl50520150305-2202)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "product = ... " message you refer to is from the first line of messages.log and is correct, as this refers to how the Liberty instance is registered (see message CWWKB0108I further down), as in this instance you are using the Liberty provided by CICS TS.

As to your problem "JCICS is not recognized", JCICS is provided by the cicsts:core-1.0 product extension, so no obvious reason for it not to be available if you have that configured.

Can you clarify a couple of issues which will help narrow this down

1. What errors do you see and in which logs
2. What features does Liberty report as actually configured - see msg CWWKF0012I in messages.log

Comment: Phil, Thanks for very quick reply. I am uploading complete log here. Our program is using IsCICS to check if we are running in CICS and the program is getting into "not running in cics" section.

Comment: comments section has a limit. I will edit and upload the log

Answer (score 0):

< product = CICS Transaction Server for z/OS 5.1.0, CICS LIBERTY NOTUSAGE, WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5, WAS FOR Z/OS 8.5.5.5 (wlp-1.0.8.cl50520150305-2202) >

< wlp.install.dir = /opt/local/lpp/cicsts/cicsts51/PC/wlp/ >

< server.config.dir = /lpp/wss/common/cics/cicsfn11/work/CIC#FN11/WLPWINS2/wlp/usr/servers/wlpwins2/ >

< java.home = /usr/lpp/java/J7.0_64 >

< java.version = 1.7.0 >

< java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (pmz6470sr9fp10-20150708_01 (SR9 FP10)) >

< os = z/OS (02.01.00; s390x) (en_US) >

< process = 33752595@L2 >

< ******************************************************************************** >

< 11/13/15 11:22:37:794 EST¨ 00000012 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0001I: The server wlpwins2 has been launched. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:38:490 EST¨ 0000001b com.ibm.ws.config.xml.internal.XMLConfigParser               A CWWKG0028A: Processing included configuration resource: /lpp/wss/common/cics/cicsfn11/work/CIC#FN11/WLPWINS2/wlp/usr/servers/wlpwins2/installedApps.xml >

< 11/13/15 11:22:38:496 EST¨ 0000001b com.ibm.ws.config.xml.internal.XMLConfigParser               A CWWKG0028A: Processing included configuration resource: /lpp/wss/common/cics/cicsfn11/work/CIC#FN11/WLPWINS2/wlp/usr/servers/wlpwins2/cicsSsl.xml >

< 11/13/15 11:22:38:826 EST¨ 00000012 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           I CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 1.031 seconds >

< 11/13/15 11:22:38:892 EST¨ 00000024 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0007I: Feature update started. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:39:715 EST¨ 00000027 org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl  I Bundle com.ibm.ws.eba.tx.7.0 is waiting for dependencies Ý(objectClass=javax.transaction.TransactionManager), (objectClass=com.ibm.ws.LocalTransaction.LocalTransactionCurrent)¨ >

< 11/13/15 11:22:39:725 EST¨ 0000001b com.ibm.ws.security.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl        I CWWKS0007I: The security service is starting... >

< 11/13/15 11:22:39:905 EST¨ 0000001d com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore                             E CWPKI0033E: The keystore located at /lpp/wss/common/cics/cicsfn11/work/CIC#FN11/WLPWINS2/wlp/usr/servers/wlpwins2/resources/security/key.jks did not load because of the following error: Invalid keystore format >

< 11/13/15 11:22:39:908 EST¨ 0000001d com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore                             W CWPKI0809W: There is a failure loading the defaultKeyStore keystore. If an SSL configuration is references the defaultKeyStore keystore, then the configuration fails to initialize. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:020 EST¨ 00000027 org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl  I Bundle com.ibm.ws.eba.tx.7.0 is waiting for dependencies Ý(objectClass=javax.transaction.TransactionManager)¨ >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:178 EST¨ 00000028 org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl  I Bundle com.ibm.ws.org.apache.aries.application.resolver.obr.1.0.1 is waiting for dependencies Ý(objectClass=org.apache.aries.application.management.spi.runtime.LocalPlatform)¨ >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:179 EST¨ 00000028 org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl  I Bundle com.ibm.ws.org.apache.aries.application.resolver.obr.1.0.1 is waiting for dependencies Ý(objectClass=org.apache.aries.application.management.spi.runtime.LocalPlatform)¨ >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:482 EST¨ 0000002b com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host L2.mf.jpmchase.net  (IPv4: 155.180.183.41) port 52561. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:633 EST¨ 00000017 LogService-127-com.ibm.cics.wlp.impl                         E CWWKE0702E: Could not resolve module: com.ibm.cics.wlp.impl Ý127¨ >

Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.ibm.wsspi.bytebuffer >

< 
11/13/15 11:22:40:731 EST¨ 0000001b com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named baseCache initialized successfully. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:733 EST¨ 0000001b com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1071I: The cache provider default is being used. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:738 EST¨ 0000001b com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:745 EST¨ 0000002a com.ibm.ws.security.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl        I CWWKS0008I: The security service is ready. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:746 EST¨ 0000002a com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPAKeyCreator       I CWWKS4105I: LTPA configuration is ready after 0.385 seconds. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:885 EST¨ 00000024 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0015I: The server has the following interim fixes installed: PI29785,PI36563. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:886 EST¨ 00000024 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: Ýssl-1.0, json-1.0, appSecurity-2.0, blueprint-1.0, cicsts:security-1.0, jsp-2.2, servlet-3.0, jaxrs-1.1, jndi-1.0, cicsts:core-1.0, distributedMap-1.0, wab-1.0¨. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:886 EST¨ 00000024 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 2.061 seconds. >

< 11/13/15 11:22:40:886 EST¨ 00000024 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The server wlpwins2 is ready to run a smarter planet. >